# PHPMYADMIN User Access

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

Ok so I got one linux(centos) dedicated server. I was paying someone to look after my server. Now I remember for security purpose I asked him to disable access to PHPMYADMIN for all user exvept root. Now I want to enable access to phpmyadmin for one user only.

how can I do that, so that specific user can access phpmyadmin through cpanel/whm ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try asking your hosting provider? They'll have the info you need to answer this question

Comment: they don't provide these sort of support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply create a new user in phpmyadmin? Then you have root and the new user who can connect to the database. Unless you meant that the restriction is on server side (server user), that's a whole different story.

Comment: yes that can solve this. Can I get the instructions please !!

Comment: Enter phpmyadmin and click on tab Privileges. There you can manage existing database users, create new users and define their rights.